# How to download and install a certificate?

Tags: php, certificate

I'd to download and install certificate for https access from my web site for a specific usage...

if I access to mywebsite/mycertificate.crt, the download is done and then the certificate installation program is launched. So it's ok.

Now, I want to download it via a webservice.

But that way, it only downloads it in `Downloads` folder.. I suppose I didn't set `Content-Type` correctly.

So my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Download my certificate</title>
    </head>
    <BODY>
        <?php
        if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'android') !== false) {
            if (file_exists('./mycertificate.crt')) {
                header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
                header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for internet explorer
                header("Content-Type: application/crt");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
                header("Content-Length:".filesize('./mycertificate.crt'));
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mycertificate.crt");
                readfile('./mycertificate.crt');
            } else {
                die('ERROR');
            }
        } else {
            die('Bad device');
        }
        ?>

    </BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: `application/crt`? Can you cite a somewhat authoritative source for that mime type? For `application/pkix-cert` that would be https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2585.html#section-4.1 and for `application/x-x509-user-cert` ...ah, I guess I could find it on some old netscape site ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK. I tried `crt` but just like that... and `pkix-cert` seems to refer .cer files instead of .crt. I think I tried the last one without success but I'm going to try again. Thanks.

Comment: `application/pkix-cert`marks content that "Carries a cryptographic certificate" more or les regardless of the extension of a file (if a file is involved). IIS4 associated both file extensions (c.er and .crt) with the mime type application/x-x509-ca-cert, IIS 7 by default serves them as application/pkix-cert. mime-type and file extension are not really the same thing.